# Change DataGrid column header text

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a list of a specific class type `Person` and I want to make a `DataGrid` with it.

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    List<Person> x; //Don't worry, x has data in it
    (sender as DataGrid).ItemsSource = x;
}
```

And the `Person` class:

```
class Person {
    string fName, lName;
}
```

After all this I get a table with the headers: "fName" and "lName". How can I change that to: "First Name" and "Last Name"?

Comment: Don't auto generate columns. Create them manually. Check [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html) link

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here the Right way to do it :

**First** Define an `ObservableCollection` in the codebehind that will hold a list of persons

**Second** Bind that list to the **DataGrid** **ItemSource** and Bind its properties

You can change what name to display on each column by simply disabling the `AutoGenerateColumns` and setting their names by your self

here the full code

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListPersons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

and the code behind :

```
public class Person
{
    public String FName { get; set; }   
    public String LName { get; set; }   

}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> ListPersons { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ListPersons=new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person()
            {
                FName = "FName1",
                LName = "LName1"
            },
             new Person()
            {
                FName = "FName2",
                LName = "LName2"
            }

        };
        this.DataContext = this;

    }


}
```

Comment: define a new one as property, and use the old one to instantiate it:
ListPersons=new ObservableCollection<Person>(yourOldLis)

Answer (score 21):

you can set :

```
 myDataGrid.Columns[0].Header="First Name";
 myDataGrid.Columns[1].Header="Last Name";
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use sql for getting data, I mean don't use entity framework you can use an Alias for your columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
(sender as DataGrid).Columns[0].Header="First Name";
(sender as DataGrid).Columns[1].Header="Last Name";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try HeaderText instead of Header like this :

```
  myDataGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText="First Name";
  myDataGrid.Columns[1].HeaderText="Last Name";
```

Comment: Just a note, I found this in another page but you have to make sure that you set the Headers before you Bind the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
myDataGrid.Columns[0].Header="First Name";    
myDataGrid.Columns[1].Header="Last Name";
```

all them work for me but you have to put code after datagrid loaded

Comment: It has been so long that I don't think I even remember C#... (jk). Seriously though, @apomene already answered this.