# Read Excel with column cell name

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, dataadapter

I am reading an Excel file and displaying in DataGrid. I need to display the column cell name along with the cell values. For ex., if I have any value in column A, the data table's header should display as A, B, C, …, AA, BB, … But here I am seeing F1, F2, …

This is the image i'm getting.

[image]

I want the format as below.

[image] And here is my code.

```
string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName +
               ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;';";

using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
{                
    string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$G1:L20]";

    OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectQuery, con);
    oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel);                       
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can change the header text with `myDataGrid.Columns[0].Header = "blah";` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477846/change-datagrid-column-header-text

Comment: Personally, I would user [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) or a similar, free NuGet package to read from an Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

After your datatable is built, just alter the column names as such:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtexcel.Columns.Count; i++)
    dtexcel.Columns[i].ColumnName = GetExcelColumnName(i + 7);
```

`+7` is there because you started on column G.  If you started on A, it would be `+1`.

The `GetExcelColumnName` method can be poached from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/1278553

To give you some confidence this works, I tried it on a sample project:

[image]