# Data Grid View Column name change

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm writing a program with c sharp. I am using Data grid view and I put the dt object directly to the DataSource method. How can I change the column names?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQWsO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmqBF.png)

```html
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            db.Open();
            string query = "select * from BackupList";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, db);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            db.Close();

            dgw_backupList.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: So you do __not__ actually want to change the colum Names (which is not possible) but the header Texts which is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't say if you're working on WPF or WinForm, I suppose you're using WPF.
You have a couple of options:

1. XAML: change your DataGrid setting AutoGenerateColumns property to false, then manually write all the columns you want to show (and you can specify any header)
2. Code behind (C#): after you add your data source, you can change the header of each column

In this post you can find both examples: [Change DataGrid column header text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477846/change-datagrid-column-header-text/28477985)

Comment: The post clearly is about Winforms.